# Can't find location for bought app

Tags: applications, geolocation

I have a Xiaomi Redmi Note 3, running android 5.0.2 (LRX22G... if that helps). I've just bought an app from the play store. It's a GPS app where I'd like to find the location of the saved APK and then move it into sys, so I can root it. I can't find the original APK, though. Yes, I've searched in /data/app and system/app... nothing there. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For secure apps, You need to find the correct folder, Like data/secure-apps/apps

Comment: Also I hadn't realised that I needed to root my phone to find these as well. I probably confused my language in the question because of this. Oops.